# What are the guidelines on accepting an answer but editing the code it provided

Tags: discussion

I recently answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534014/download-data-from-internet-in-background-and-concurrently-share-them-among-all/34534613?noredirect=1#comment56900698_34534613) for a new user. Today he added a comment to thank me and let me know he had changed my answer at the same time.

It wasn't malicious but it doesn't seem acceptable for future users viewing the answer and as expected the edit was unanimously [rejected by reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10760387)

Now my question is, what's the correct way to approach this situation when it happens? I presume in this case it only got flagged for review as a suggested edit because it's a new user, if that had not happened I would probably have rolled back the answer as it isn't code I would be happy to offer as an answer to this question. But what is the correct thing to tell the OP to do?

Would it be correct to either suggest adding it as a separate answer (which means my answer not being the accepted one) or editing the question to add it below? (I've seen a lot of it, but is that ever right?), or maybe I should change my own answer to better match their code sample?

Comment: It is never ok to add a solution to the question. If the edit is as extensive as the one referenced here, reject it or roll it back and tell the user to add their own answer if they really think it is all that useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that the revision is far too extensive to be acceptable. I'm glad the reviewing system worked.

A general guideline for editing someone else's posts is that it shouldn't add nor remove anything from what the OP originaly intended to cover. It should be an effort to help *convey* their message better.

So it's alright to correct obvious spelling or syntax errors ("it's" => "its", `HtppRequest` => `HttpRequest`), or even obvious linguistic errors, and of course formatting (please!). Generally, the revisions should be pretty minor.

If anybody feels any inclination to edit a post to a point where it significantly changes the original message (even when it could be a significant improvement), they should either leave a comment or (when it's an answer) post a new answer.